# Selenium AttributeError: list object has no attribute find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am attempting to perform some scraping of nutritional data from a website, and everything seems to be going swimmingly so far, until I run into pages that are formatted slightly different.

Using selenium and a line like this, returns an empty list:

```
values = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('size-12-fl-oz' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value')
```

print would return this:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

But if I define out the element position, then it works fine:

```
kcal = data.find_elements_by_xpath("(.//div[@class='size-12-fl-oz nutrition-value' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value'])[position()=1]").text
```

The issue I have ran into, is when the elements are not the same from page to page as I iterate. So if a div does not exist in position 9, then an error is thrown.

Now when I go back and try to edit my code to do a `try/catch`, I am getting:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

or

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Here is the code, with my commented out areas from my testing back and forth.

```
import requests, bs4, urllib2, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException    

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
...

#Loop on URLs to get Nutritional Information from each one.
with open('products.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        url = line
#        url = 'http://www.tapintoyourbeer.com/index.cfm?id=3'
        browser.get(url)
        with open("output.csv", "a") as o:
            writeFile = csv.writer(o)
            browser.implicitly_wait(3)
            product_name = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text.title() #Get product name
            size = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='dotted-tab'])").text #Get product size
            data = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='beer-data-table']")
#            values=[]
#            values = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('size-12-fl-oz' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value')
            try:
#            values = data.find_elements_by_xpath("(.//div[@class='size-12-fl-oz nutrition-value' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value'])")
                kcal = data.find_element_by_xpath("(.//div[@class='size-12-fl-oz nutrition-value' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value'])[position()=1]").text
                kj = data.find_element_by_xpath("(.//div[@class='size-12-fl-oz nutrition-value' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value'])[position()=3]").text
                fat = data.find_element_by_xpath("(.//div[@class='size-12-fl-oz nutrition-value' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value'])[position()=5]").text
                carbs = data.find_element_by_xpath("(.//div[@class='size-12-fl-oz nutrition-value' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value'])[position()=7]").text
                protein = data.find_element_by_xpath("(.//div[@class='size-12-fl-oz nutrition-value' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value'])[position()=9]").text
                values = [kcal, kj, fat, carbs, protein]
                print values
                writeFile.writerow([product_name] + [size] + values)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("No Protein listed")
browser.quit()
```

I had it working earlier to produce a list, and output to a CSV, but on occasion, the position count would come out wrong.

```
[u'Budweiser', u'12 FL OZ', u'145.00', u'', u'', u'', u'']
[u"Beck'S", u'12 FL OZ', u'146.00', u'610.86', u'0.00', u'10.40', u'1.80']
[u'Bud Light', u'12 FL OZ', u'110.00', u'460.24', u'0.00', u'6.60', u'0.90']
[u'Michelob Ultra', u'12 FL OZ', u'95.00', u'397.48', u'0.00', u'2.60', u'0.60']
[u'Stella Artois', u'100 ML', u'43.30', u'KCAL/100 ML', u'181.17', u'KJ/100 ML', u'0.00']
```

The problems started when position 9 didn't exist on a particular page.

Are there any suggestions on how to fix this headache? Do I need to have cases set up for the different pages & sizes?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `find_elements()` returns either list of [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) or empty list. You're storing this result into a list variable name `data`.

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

This occurs because you're going to find nested [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) on `data` list that's why **you're calling as `data.find_element_by_xpath()` or `data.find_elements_by_xpath()` which is absolutely wrong.**

Actually [`find_element()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element) or [`find_elements()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements) is used to search the element on the **page context** or the **context of the [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)** instead of `list`.

So you should try to find individual [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) from the `data` list and then find further nested [`WebElement`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) using this element context as below :-

```
if len(data) > 0:
  #now find desire element using index
  individual_element = data[0]
 
  #now you can find further nested single element using find_element() or list of elements using find_elements() at individual_element context
  kcal = individual_element.find_element_by_xpath("(.//div[@class='size-12-fl-oz nutrition-value' or 'size-330-ml hide nutrition-value' or 'size-8-fl-oz nutrition-value'])[position()=1]").text

  ----------------------------
  ----------------------------
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.