# Finding web elements with selenium only working with .driver and not other variables

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

e.g.

This is the code used to scrape title and views from a specific channel.

```
videos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-grid-renderer")

from selenium import webdriver
driver.get("url")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

videos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-grid-renderer")

for video in videos: 
    title = videos.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]')
    views = videos.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]')
    item = {
        'title' : title, 
        'views' : views
    }
```

Error displayed in terminal:

```
title = videos.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'
```

When using `findElement()` function in **selenium**, it is only valid when its `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`, and not when driver is replaced with a variable. `(videos.find_elements_by_xpath)`

Bit of a beginner, so there might be concepts I'm missing here. I am aware of [[this post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356818/selenium-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-find-element-by-xpath) and the solution provided, but it's solution did not seem to work and was quite confusing.

If there is a concept that should be learned to solve this problem, please some resources or explanations if you can. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'
```

is cause, this line

```
title = videos.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]')
```

should have been

```
title = video.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]')
```

`videos` is a list in your code and `video` is a web element.

A list does not have `find_elements` or `find_element` function.

But a `webelement` has both the mentioned function.

so changing to `video` should get the job done.

```
for video in videos: 
    title = video.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]')
    views = video.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]')
    item = {
        'title' : title, 
        'views' : views
    }
```